# java immutable class much slower

Tags: java, performance, immutability

I was in need of some Complex math library, so I hesitated between libraries that use immutable Complex and libraries that use mutable Complex. Obviously, I want computations to run reasonably fast (unless it kills readability etc.).

So I created simple test of speed mutable vs immutable:

```
final class MutableInt {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MutableInt() {
        this(0);
    }

    public MutableInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }   
}

final class ImmutableInt {
    private final int value;

    public ImmutableInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class TestImmutableSpeed {

    static long testMutable(final int arrLen) {
        MutableInt[] arrMutable = new MutableInt[arrLen];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrMutable.length; ++i) {
            arrMutable[i] = new MutableInt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < arrMutable.length; ++j) {
                arrMutable[i].setValue(arrMutable[i].getValue() + j);
            }
        }
        long sumMutable = 0;
        for (MutableInt item : arrMutable) {
            sumMutable += item.getValue();
        }
        return sumMutable;
    }

    static long testImmutable(final int arrLen) {
        ImmutableInt[] arrImmutable = new ImmutableInt[arrLen];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrImmutable.length; ++i) {
            arrImmutable[i] = new ImmutableInt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < arrImmutable.length; ++j) {
                arrImmutable[i] = new ImmutableInt(arrImmutable[i].getValue() + j);
            }
        }
        long sumImmutable = 0;
        for (ImmutableInt item : arrImmutable) {
            sumImmutable += item.getValue();
        }
        return sumImmutable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int arrLen = 1<<14;

        long tmStart = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("sum = " + testMutable(arrLen));
        long tmMid = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("sum = " + testImmutable(arrLen));
        long tmEnd = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("speed comparison mutable vs immutable:");
        System.out.println("mutable   " + (tmMid - tmStart)/1000000 + " ms");
        System.out.println("immutable " + (tmEnd - tmMid)/1000000 + " ms");
    }
}
```

You can adjust size of array if the test runs too slow/fast.

I run with: -server -Xms256m -XX:+AggressiveOpts
And I get:

```
sum = 2199023247360
sum = 2199023247360
speed comparison mutable vs immutable:
mutable   102 ms
immutable 1506 ms
```

Question: Am I missing some optimization parameter, or is immutable version 15x slower?

If it is, why would anyone write math library with immutable class Complex in it? Is immutable just "fancy" but useless?

I know that immutable class is safer as hash map key or can't have race conditions, but that are special cases that can be handled without immutability everywhere.

**Edit:** I re-run this microbenchmark with caliper, as suggested by one answer, and it runs 12x slower, not 15x, still the same point. Changed code for Caliper benchmarking:

```
import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;



final class MutableInt {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MutableInt() {
        this(0);
    }

    public MutableInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }   
}

final class ImmutableInt {
    private final int value;

    public ImmutableInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}


public class TestImmutableSpeed extends SimpleBenchmark {

    static long testMutable(final int arrLen) {
        MutableInt[] arrMutable = new MutableInt[arrLen];
        for (int i = 0; i
```

Output of Caliper:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Mutable, type=-server, minMemory=-Xms256m, optimizations=-XX:+AggressiveOpts} 91614044.60 ns; ?=250338.20 ns @ 3 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Immutable, type=-server, minMemory=-Xms256m, optimizations=-XX:+AggressiveOpts} 1108057922.00 ns; ?=3920760.98 ns @ 3 trials

benchmark     ms linear runtime
  Mutable   91.6 ==
Immutable 1108.1 ==============================
```

Note that without the optimization parameters for JVM output of Caliper is:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Mutable} 516562214.00 ns; ?=623120.57 ns @ 3 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Immutable} 1706758503.00 ns; ?=5842389.60 ns @ 3 trials

benchmark   ms linear runtime
  Mutable  517 =========
Immutable 1707 ==============================
```

So bad parameters make both version slow, but ratio is less terrible (but not important, still).

Comment: Yeah, thats why I use [mutable wrappers](http://jodd.org/api/jodd/mutable/package-summary.html) when speed matters (like, always:) and when I need to have objects. 3x ratio is more likely then 15x.

Comment: I hadn't seen that there was more code - scroll areas inside scroll areas. Makes more sense. You can't really have microbenchmarking switching between algorithms like that. Not even if you do it several times in a big loop.

Comment: @ɹoƃı ratio is (cost of allocation) / (speed of calculation per allocation), so it changes with algorithm and class. For this particular case, speed of "int" is super fast for calculation, and ratio is higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutability comes sometimes with speed penalty. Use math library with mutable Complex, if speed matters.

Comment: I was revisiting this again, and I realized that your `Immutable` case constructs a new object at every iteration of the inner loop, whereas the `Mutable` one does not. So this has more to do with object construction/destruction than anything else, especially with very restrictive memory settings (as the garbage collector will run more often). I did a test where the two versions use identical behavior, and the `Immutable` one was actually faster.

Comment: Of course, new object construction is bottleneck for immutable classes, that is what the question is all about. It could be without construction/destruction if there are "unique types" or you use locally visible variables (and jvm that can optimize for it, which was not the case for official vm).

Answer (score 6):

This is fascinating. Well, first of all, that is not a fair test; you aren't warming up the JVM when you do it that way. Benchmarking is typically very difficult to do. I refactored your code to use [Google Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/), and got similar, yet different results; the immutable class was only 3 times slower. Not sure why yet. Anyway here's the work so far:

### TestImmutableSpeed.java

```
import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class TestImmutableSpeed {
    static final class MutableInt {
        private int value;

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public MutableInt() {
            this(0);
        }

        public MutableInt(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }   
    }

    static final class ImmutableInt {
        private final int value;

        public ImmutableInt(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static class TestBenchmark extends SimpleBenchmark {
        public void timeMutable(final int arrLen) {
            MutableInt[] arrMutable = new MutableInt[arrLen];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrMutable.length; ++i) {
                arrMutable[i] = new MutableInt(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < arrMutable.length; ++j) {
                    arrMutable[i].setValue(arrMutable[i].getValue() + j);
                }
            }
            long sumMutable = 0;
            for (MutableInt item : arrMutable) {
                sumMutable += item.getValue();
            }
            System.out.println(sumMutable);
        }

        public void timeImmutable(final int arrLen) {
            ImmutableInt[] arrImmutable = new ImmutableInt[arrLen];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrImmutable.length; ++i) {
                arrImmutable[i] = new ImmutableInt(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < arrImmutable.length; ++j) {
                    arrImmutable[i] = new ImmutableInt(arrImmutable[i].getValue() + j);
                }
            }
            long sumImmutable = 0;
            for (ImmutableInt item : arrImmutable) {
                sumImmutable += item.getValue();
            }
            System.out.println(sumImmutable);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner.main(TestBenchmark.class, new String[0]);
    }
}
```

### Caliper Output

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Immutable} 78574.05 ns; σ=21336.61 ns @ 10 trials
 50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Mutable} 24956.94 ns; σ=7267.78 ns @ 10 trials

 benchmark   us linear runtime
 Immutable 78.6 ==============================
   Mutable 25.0 =========

 vm: java
 trial: 0
```

### String update

So I was thinking about this more, and I decided to try changing the wrapped class from an `int` to an object, in this case a `String`. Changing the static classes to `String`s, and loading the strings with `Integer.valueOf(i).toString()`, and instead of adding, appending them in a `StringBuilder`, I got these results:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Immutable} 11034616.91 ns; σ=7006742.43 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Mutable} 9494963.68 ns; σ=6201410.87 ns @ 10 trials

benchmark    ms linear runtime
Immutable 11.03 ==============================
  Mutable  9.49 =========================

vm: java
trial: 0
```

However, I think in this case the difference is dominated by all the array copying that would have to happen, and not the fact that it was using `String`s.

Comment: Could you post results for the array of the same length when not using Caliper? To see if it is not making the mutable version run slower (in total ms). I played with optimization parameters and some of them made jvm run much slower for both immutable and mutable version (but mutable version wasn't much faster in that case).

Comment: @peenut I don't understand your request, you did it without using Caliper already. Caliper automatically runs the test using the same array lengths; in fact it does it 10 times at different lengths after warming up the JVM.

Comment: your computer has different speed. I just wanted to see the results, if you run jvm with parameters I listed in question, if Caliper makes it run faster (and thus I am wrong with my test), or not (and Caliper is wrong). I have no experience with Caliper yet, and their wiki is currently dead, so I can't really try it for myself.

Comment: @peenut Unfortunately I have to get back to work. It's available on maven, you can download it manually here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.caliper|caliper|0.5-rc1|jar

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and it is indeed 3x slower with this benchmark, not 15x.

Comment: I put +1 to point out microbenchmark might be needed, and -1 because you microbenchmarked without optimization parameters :) It runs 12x slower, what is practically the same as 15x.

Comment: @peenut -1 for an answer that helped you? That's super high standards

Comment: Anyway I left +1, but it didn't help with question at all. It just showed me unrelated mistake - that I might use some library/software for microbenchmarks, instead of "raw" running. Would you please consider editing your answer with re-run of tests with optimization parameters? Your answer is a bit misleading right now.

Comment: I removed +1, "String Update" sounds like terrible idea (using String for concatenation instead of StringBuilder, and measuring the speed?!). I suggest you post some code to your "String Update" section or remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Immutable values make clean programming in Java cleaner. You don't have to copy everywhere to avoid ending up with spooky action at a distance (by which I mean changing a value in one place inadvertently changes a value in another). Removing the copy speeds things up in places, but creating new instances slows things down in other areas.

(C++ is interesting in that it takes the opposite approach. You get copies at well defined points without having to write any code. Indeed you have to write code in order to remove the copying.)

If your concern is for performance, a mutable complex is no good either. Much better to have, say, a complex array class which uses a single double array hidden in the implementation, or just the double array raw.

Back in the nineties, Guy Steele mentioned the idea of adding value types to Java as part of making the language itself complete. Although that was a very limited proposal, similar
structs C# later introduced, but neither copes with arguably the most obvious value class in Java, the string.

Comment: So, basically, mutable in Java is slow, but immutable is terribly slow?

Comment: @peenut For numerical work, small objects are generally slow in Java. Even in C or C++ you would typically allocate large numbers of small values in an array rather than individual heap allocations, although placed on the stack works well for small objects.

Comment: Hawtin: C/C++ version is faster, because you can create array of values, instead of array of pointers to values - better locality of reference. I cannot imagine why would anyone allocate on heap in C++ for example I provided in question.

Comment: oh, and I should have noted I added +1, because it's good point and I agree

Comment: I tested speed of int[] vs speed of MutableInt[] and it's practically the same speed. MutableInt is perfectly fast enough (just takes a bit more memory).